# Odd parenthesis spacing in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, parenthesis

I'm using Beamer for the first time.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{parskip}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{commath}

% caps
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{asymptote}

% units
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setdefaultlanguage{french}

% fonts
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\input{commands}
```

However,

```
\begin{equation}
I_1\ddot{\theta} + \od{\!V}{\theta}(\theta(t)) = 0
\end{equation}
```

produces this undesirable spacing issue around (t) :
[image]

It's really minor, but nevertheless irks me. Where does it come from ?

Comment: For strange reasons, the font used for math letters is text italic, which is a rather crazy thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `serif` font theme does a rather crazy thing: it sets the font for math letters to the text italic font rather than the right math font.

You can either use `unicode-math` or reinstate the correct font:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}

% caps
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{asymptote}

% units
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setdefaultlanguage{french}

% fonts
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareSymbolFont{pureletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}%
  \SetSymbolFont{pureletters}{bold}{OML}{cmm}{bf}{it}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
I_1\ddot{\theta} + \frac{dV}{d\theta}(\theta(t)) = 0
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Don't use `commath` for any reason: it's buggy and has unpredictable results. If you need the upright “d” for the differential add

```
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
```

and use `\diff` for the differential “d“.

[image]

Comment: Didn't know that 'commath' was a mess. Thanks for the heads up.